# Brand new - never been used stainless steel briage pot pitted with one 6 minute water boil on my gas range

Tags: boiling

I had pitting in an All-Clad pot and figured I had done something wrong ( no salt added at all just water boiled).  The new pot ( received yesterday) .. washed with hot water and soap, cleaned, dried and commenced to heating.. it's already pitting.. I live near Carlsbad, CA and I do believe the water here is quite "hard".. ( chlorine, calcium)..    any suggestions appreciated.
Kevin[image: added pictures of brand new - 1 boil of water only brigade pan and multi-boil all clad pan]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the surface?

Comment: Are you sure it's pitting and not just discoloration?

Comment: Is it possibly just limescale, created from the calcium in your water? If so it should be quite easy to remove using some vinegar or citric acid.

Comment: Johanna pictures added..  the brigade- just one water-from-faucet boil.. .. the all-clad - many boils ( water - no salt)..     J.Mueller thank you - this looks like pitting but i'll try anything..

Answer (score 2):

This is not pitting, this is scale. You can't prevent it, no matter what kind of pot you buy.

Washing/scrubbing won't really help. Get a descaling agent - no need to go for the expensive ones, maybe just get some citric acid in bulk - and descale whenever it builds up enough to bother you.

Comment: Agreed. No need to worry, it´s just an optical issue, but does not harm neither pots nor health.